# How can I compare just the dates of datetime in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a query in `SQLAlchemy`:

```
weekly_schedule = WeeklyHour.query.filter(
    and_(
        WeeklyHour.start_time.in_(week_dates),
        WeeklyHour.end_time.in_(week_dates),
        WeeklyHour.employee == employee
        )
    ).all()
```

I am getting the dates of the current week like so:

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
week_dates = [today + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in xrange(0 - today.weekday(), 7 - today.weekday())]
```

This returns a list of the current week in `datetimes`. Like so:

```
[datetime.date(2014, 4, 7), datetime.date(2014, 4, 8), datetime.date(2014, 4, 9), datetime.date(2014, 4, 10), datetime.date(2014, 4, 11), datetime.date(2014, 4, 12), datetime.date(2014, 4, 13)]
```

The problem is that the `WeeklyHour` is a `datetime` when the employee started and ended that day. And `week_dates` are a specific time set to `now()`.  I will never get results because the `time` of the `datetime` won't match. All I really want to compare is the `date` portion of the `datetime`. My current solution (which works but is dumb) is to store separate `dates` of the `datetime`.

Comment: what database do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than querying "in" all days of the week use the days as limits.

```
today = date.today()
start_of_week = today - timedelta(days=today.weekday())
start_of_following_week = start_of_week + timedelta(days=7)

weekly_schedule = WeeklyHour.query.filter(
    and_(
        WeeklyHour.start_time >= start_of_week,  # On or after Monday
        WeeklyHour.end_time < start_of_following_week, # Before next Monday
        WeeklyHour.employee == employee
        )
    ).all()
```

Comment: As it happens, the and_() call surrounding all those conditions is not required as it's the default mode for .query.filter().